# some weird values that i can't insert it into my psql table

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I downloaded a data file crawled from an auto information website.
Basically it looks like this:
[image]
 [image]

after I import it using \i in psql.
i got this error:

```
Invalid command \',. Try \? for help.
```

i tried the create table part without insert any rows. it can create a table successfully. 
and i manually insert some rows from this file. some of them works, others doesn't.

so i guess there are some weird values in the values that i insert.
some weird values like '前● / 后●' can be insert, but until i found this:

```
'[u\'#70706E\', u\'#854C38\']'
```

when i insert this, it gives me the same error message.

Could some one tell me what does this value mean? why it can't be insert and how do they get it when they use crawler to crawl the data from the website?

Comment: MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I think this is the issue of character encoding.